# No .designer.cs and .resx files created for .cs files when creating an outlook add-in project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, outlook-addin

I created a new outlook add-in project in visual studio 2013 but no .designer and.resx files were created. But designer.xml was created. How can I add those other 2 files?

Any suggestions will prevent me from blocking further!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a Ribbon designer to a project:

1. On the Project Menu, click Add New Item.
2. In the Add New Item dialog box, select Ribbon (Visual Designer). For more information about these templates, see [Ribbon Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx).
3. In the Name box, type a name for the Ribbon item.
4. Click OK.

See [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.